# Difference between Can you please explain me or Could you please explain me

Tags: meaning-in-context

Which one is best and why ?.

Can you please explain me or

Could you please explain me.

Comment: Both are ungrammatical, so neither one is better. _Could_ is felt by some people to be more polite in a request than _can_. But you should get the grammar right before you worry about abstract points of politeness. _Explain_ does not take an indirect object, and therefore you have to say _explain **to** me_, not **explain me*. It's a common mistake, but not something a native speaker would ever say, unless they were making fun of someone's accent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for the better of two ungrammatical sentences.

Comment: If you want to preserve your aspect of the question that involves using "explain me," please consider revising the question to ask why that phrase isn't used in idiomatic English. If instead you are especially interested in whether "can you please explain to me" or "could you please explain to me" is preferable, please add the preposition "to" to your question (both in the header, twice, and in the body of the question, twice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit hard to understand, but I'm assuming you meant to write

> Can you please explain it **to** me?
>
> Would you please explain it **to** me?

If this is what you meant to write, then *would* means that you would like someone to explain it to you. *Can*, in context, would refer to if you can explain it. In other words, *can* sounds more demanding and *would* means it's optional or something.

Comment: I disagree - I think the question is about the difference between can and could not can and would... but I might be wrong...

Comment: Maybe you're right...I only corrected some grammatical errors and provided a brief description...

Comment: but I think your answer is also helpful and the can vs would question is also interesting +1

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Relentive you missed a 'to' in each sentence.

So the differences between

- Can you please explain to me?

and

- Could you please explain to me?

In the second sentence the verb (could) is in the conditional tense (I think) - but can is in the present (I think).

The difference in meaning is small.

'Could you' is more polite than 'Can you' and it sounds better - particularly if you are asking someone to do something for you.